# How to apply regex to specific column in awk

Tags: regex, linux, awk, ls

```
la() {
     ls -lhAXF "$@" | awk '
     BEGIN {
         FPAT = "([[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+)";
     } {
         $1 = "\033[1m" "\033[31m" $1 "\033[0m";
         $2 = "\033[1m" "\033[32m" $2 "\033[0m";
         $3 = "\033[1m" "\033[33m" $3 "\033[0m";
         $4 = "\033[34m" $4 "\033[0m";
         $5 = "\033[1m" "\033[35m" $5 "\033[0m";
         $6 = "\033[1m" "\033[36m" $6 "\033[0m";
         $7 = "\033[1m" "\033[37m" $7 "\033[0m";
         $8 = "\033[1m" "\033[33m" $8 "\033[0m";
         print
     }'
}
```

This will colorize the output of ls -lhAXF
How to apply the color to specific type of item using regex, for example i want the folder to be green, the .config folder red, the regular file blue or something like that.

folder - match $9 column containing '/' in the end of word
hidden folder - match $9 column containing '.' in the start of word
regular file - the rest of unmatched in column $9

how to apply regex to specific column like that in awk?
I'm using Debian 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*how to apply regex to specific column like that in awk?*

Syntax for that in GNU `AWK` is as follows

```
$1~/pattern/
```

where `1` is number of column. Consider following simple example, let `file.txt`

```
1. ABC
2. 123
3. DEF
```

then

```
awk '{print $2~/^[0-9]*$/}' file.txt
```

output

```
0
1
0
```

Explanation: This does check if 2nd column (`$2`) content consist solely of digits. `^` denotes begin of field and `$` denotes end of field.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*